# What actually happen when i connect an external display to ubuntu pc

Tags: 12.04, display

I know that Ubuntu treats an external device as an file, for eg. when i connect an external webcam to my pc, a file named as video1 creates under my dev directory. I just want to know that does ubuntu handles external display the same way and how we can configure/select from multiple displays connected to a pc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR

Answer (score 0):

**GUI**
open `Displays` from unity. Then press *Detect Display* if not found

**CLI**
**xrandr**
Use `xrandr` to use and configure the display

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>      1366x768       60.0*+
>      1360x768       59.8     60.0
>      1024x768       60.0
>      800x600        60.3     56.2
>      640x480        59.9
>   VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)